# È necessario eu adicionar Microsoft.net.http? monoAndroid?

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget

estou tentanto fazer meu app passar dados atravez de uma web api. Pórem tento colocar o pacote Microsoft.net.http pelo nugetPackage porém ele retora em erro. Se for necessário como resolvo isso? 
O

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloca o erro que está sendo apresentado, fica melhor pra te ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é necessário adicionar um pacote, porém você está tentando adicionar o pacote errado.

O nome do pacote é *System.Net.Http*

#### 1. Adicionando o pacote

- Clique com o botão direito sobre as Referências do seu projeto e selecione a opção *Manage NuGet Pacakages*...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Na tela aberta, clique na aba *Browse* ou *Procurar*, digite *system.net.http*, clique sobre o pacote mostrado na imagem e depois clique em *Instalar* ou *Install*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Feito isso você poderá utilizar a biblioteca System.Net.Http para fazer requisições HTTP como por exemplo consumir uma API.

#### 2. Utilizando a biblioteca System.Net.Http

- Para utilizar essa biblioteca, primeiramente adicione dois *using* no topo da sua classe (apenas o primeiro é necessário, mas já que irá consumir uma Web API, já pode adicionar os dois pois irá precisar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Feito isso, você pode começar a criar os métodos para consumir a API que você deseja. Abaixo segue uma imagem de exemplo e um link de um artigo que mostra como realizar operações REST em uma Web API.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Artigo: [Consumindo RESTful Web Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/)